# JSONObject Android failed to create

Tags: android, json

I have GetRequest and as a response I got HTML head and the content of body element is Array of JSONS. Iam unable to parse it, could anyone post a tip how to create JSON Object from this response??

Answer (score 0):

If you have your JSON return value in `String json` you can do

```
JSONArray a = new JSONArray(json);
```

The first JSONObject in the array can then be retrieved with

```
JSONObject o = a.getJSONObject(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JSON Object from a string like this.

```
String myString = "This is the response from your HTTP GET request";
JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(myString);
```

Note that the value of `myString` must be valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Creating JSON Parser instance
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

try {
// Getting Array of Contacts
contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

// looping through All Contacts
for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

    // Storing each json item in variable
    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
    String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

    // Phone number is agin JSON Object
    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
    String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
    String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

}
} catch (JSONException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, when I downloaded request from server I have to get only content of   element. Than I used standard JSONArray and everything is working fine.